# Trying to pull lines from a text file puting it into a list in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got it for the most part but when I put the unicode into a list the program does it letter by letter instead of as a whole. A single list full of the unicode was my goal.

```
with open('emoji-data.txt', 'rt') as in_file:
  for line in in_file:
    if ';' in line:
        uni = line[:4]
        s = line[6:11]
        second = (s.lstrip('.'))
        cleanuni = (uni.lstrip('# @m'))
        new = list(cleanuni)
        print(new)
```

Comment: I would add the output of the code but I do not know how to do it correctly.

Comment: `list(cleanuni)` converts a string into a list of characters. Why do you do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Start with an empty list *before* the loop: `emoji = []`.
2. Append each found word to the list: replace `new = list(cleanuni)` with `emoji.append(cleanuni)`.
3. Move the `print` outside of the loop.

Comment: thanks also I tried this the only thing I did wrong is print it inside the for loop I did not know this would happen I'm new to programming.